# Make a string null in a single line

Tags: c, for-loop

To make a string a null string i wrote this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char str[15]="fahad uddin";
    strlen(str);
    puts(str);
    for(int i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)
        strcpy(&str[i],"\0") ;
    puts(str);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

***Before this i tried:***

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char str[15]="fahad uddin";
    strlen(str);
    puts(str);
    for(int i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++,strcpy(&str[i],"\0"))
        ;
    puts(str);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

In the first example, the program runs all right while when in the second example it prints the first letter of the string (in this example F). Why is this?

Comment: In 1 line it would be `str[0] = '\0';`.

Comment: for (char*p = str; *p; *p++='\0' );

Comment: @KennyTM put this in an answer so I can vote it up

Comment: Also, the line `strlen(str);` without reading the return value has no purpose...

Comment: conio.h is not C89 or C99 standard

Comment: @gordonu mean i should prefer what ?curses.h?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C strings are null-terminated. As long as you only use the functions assuming null-terminated strings, you could just zero the first character.

```
str[0] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 8):

```
memset(str,0,strlen(str)); /* should also work */
memset(str,0,sizeof str); /* initialize the entire content */
```

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for!

Answer (score 5):

`for(int i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++,strcpy(&str[i],"\0"));` - the i++ is incrementing i before the strcpy executes - so it'll be taking the address of str[1] on the first iteration - skipping over str[0] - hence you'll get the first character.

Note that KennyTM's response is a far better way of doing this - but I guess you're learning / experimenting.

Comment: I read that the expressions proceeds from right to left.strcpy() should proceed frist then?

Comment: If you want to use this approach then yes, strcpy should be on the left hand side of the comma - the items are executed left-to-right.

Comment: I said that they proceed from left to right i.e strcpy in this example should be performed first and then i++

Answer (score 3):

Because `i++,strcpy(&str[i],"\0")` evaluates the `i++` before it evaluates the call to `strcpy()` which uses the now incremented value of `i` as its destination. In effect, it skips the first character of your string.

Note that there are much better ways to do what you want.

KennyTM mentioned just setting the first character to `'\0'` with `str[0] = '\0';`, which doesn't clear every byte but does mark the string as having zero length.

There is also `memset()` which is used to fill a block of memory with any arbitrary value, and 0 is certainly allowed.

Furthermore, calling `strcpy()` is far less efficient that just assigning to each element of `str[]` in the loop.

Answer (score -2):

Try with this code:

```
bzero(string_name, size_of_string);
```

Also, include the `<string.h>` lib file. I think this must work.

Comment: `bzero` is a legacy BSD function that duplicates the standard C `memset`. It shouldn't be recommended for new code.